# ExtJS 6 - Tag field auto width

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am dealing with ExtJS 6 [Tag field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag) and I would like to set an auto-width in the suggested tags, because if the tag names are too short there will be a huge blank space in the field.

[image: ExtJS 6 Default Tag field behaviour]

As far as I know it is supossed to work by using this two properties (but it does not work for me):

- matchFieldWidth: false
- shrinkWrap: true

The current behaviour is that the width is reduced and it breaks the lines, if the tag name is "This is a tag" it is shown in two different lines "This is" "a tag". Any ideas to achieve this goal?

Comment: This seems to work fine: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b44

Comment: I've reproduced that strange behaviour based in your example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b47